# False Boolean returned to Angular as empty object

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I have a C# API call that returns a true or false value. When it's returning the false value, it returns as an empty object, but only to Angular. When I test the same call with the same values in a REST client I get the false value that I'm expecting.

Is there a reason that I'm getting an empty object in place of a false result? I've already checked the values are being passed to the API correctly from the Angular application (which they are) and I've added a break point to the C# method to check that as it leaves the API it is definitely a false result and not an empty object.

The C# method is as follows:

```
// Check if trailblazer is on journey
[Route("Journey/TrailblazerRegistered/{journeyId}/{username}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult IsTrailblazerRegistered(string journeyId, string username)
{
    // First we assume the user is not registered
    bool UserRegistered = false;

    // Make sure we have a guid and a user
    if (journeyId == null || username == null || username == "") return NotFound();

    // If we do then get the user guid
    User UserDb = WmData.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);

    // Check we've got a user and if we have get the GUIDs
    if (UserDb == null) return NotFound();
    Guid UserGuid = UserDb.UserId;
    Guid JourneyGuid = new Guid(journeyId);

    // List of Trailblazers for this Journey
    List<UserJourney> Trailblazers = WmData.UserJourneys.Where(j => j.JourneyId == JourneyGuid).ToList();

    // See if we can find our user in that list
    UserJourney RegisteredUser = Trailblazers.Find(u => u.UserId == UserGuid);

    // Did we find a user?
    if (RegisteredUser != null) UserRegistered = true;

    // Return true / false
    return Ok(UserRegistered);
}
```

And the API call from the Angular side is:

```
// Check if Trailblazer is already on Journey
  userRegisteredToJourney() {
    this._wmapi
    .getService("Journey/TrailblazerRegistered/" + this.id + "/" + this._wmapi.tempuser)
    .then((result) => {
      this.userSignedToJourney = result;
      console.log("Journey/TrailblazerRegistered/" + this.id + "/" + this._wmapi.tempuser);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Comment: I would like to introduce you to the `String.​Is​Null​OrEmpty(String)` method, to replace those pesky `username == null || username == ""` checks. [Check it out here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I've been told that returning TRUE/FALSE from an API is ugly, because it should return Ok in such a case or throw an error which should be handled on the frontend. We're using swagger to handle all this stuff, maybe it can help you too. Would it solve the issue to warp the bool inside a "ReturnObject"?

Comment: @AsheraH I often prefer `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(String)` because it can do everything IsNullOrEmpty does but also returns false for whitespace-only strings, which is in my domain most of the time just as senseless.

Comment: Have you inspected the raw response to make sure that it is not the client causing the problem?